# Getting issue while implementing FluentUI using SPFx in SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, fluentui-react

I am following [this blog](https://www.spguides.com/retrieve-sharepoint-list-items-using-sharepoint-framework) to implement the fluentUI in SPFX part, but while doing "Gulp Build" I'm getting the following error:

```
Error - [tsc] node_modules/@fluentui/react/lib/components/GroupedList/GroupedListSection.d.ts(9,38): error TS1005: ';' expected.      
[05:38:38] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@fluentui/react/lib/components/GroupedList/GroupedListSection.d.ts(10,13): error TS1005: '=' expected.     
[05:38:38] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@fluentui/react/lib/components/GroupedList/GroupedListSection.d.ts(10,33): error TS1005: ';' expected.
[05:38:38] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@fluentui/react/lib/components/GroupedList/GroupedListSection.d.ts(11,13): error TS1005: '=' expected.
[05:38:38] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@fluentui/react/lib/components/GroupedList/GroupedListSection.d.ts(11,33): error TS1005: ';' expected.     
[05:38:38] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@fluentui/react/lib/components/GroupedList/GroupedListSection.d.ts(12,13): error TS1005: '=' expected.
[05:38:38] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@fluentui/react/lib/components/GroupedList/GroupedListSection.d.ts(12,32): error TS1005: ';' expected.     
[05:38:38] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@fluentui/react/lib/components/GroupedList/GroupFooter.d.ts(2,13): error TS1005: '=' expected.
[05:38:38] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@fluentui/react/lib/components/GroupedList/GroupFooter.d.ts(2,40): error TS1005: ';' expected.
[05:38:38] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@fluentui/react/lib/components/GroupedList/GroupFooter.d.ts(4,1): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.
[05:38:38] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@fluentui/react/lib/components/GroupedList/GroupFooter.d.ts(4,13): error TS1005: ';' expected
................
.......
.......
```

Answer (score 2):

Just had the same issue. It turns out the latest release of Fluent UI uses TypeScript 3.8 syntax, so you need to update the version used by the SPFx project. Detailed instructions here: https://www.voitanos.io/blog/use-different-typescript-versions-in-sharepoint-framework-projects/. I've actually updated mine to @microsoft/rush-stack-compiler-3.9 and it's working fine now.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following to resolve this issue:

run:

```
npm i @microsoft/rush-stack-compiler-3.2 typescript@3.2 -D -E
```

And after update the tsconfig.json file:

```
"extends": "./node_modules/@microsoft/rush-stack-compiler-3.**2**/includes/tsconfig-web.json"
```

IF this doen't help try an older version:

```
npm install @fluentui/react@7.113.0 --save
```

Comment: Tried but no luck

Comment: I have a working solution where i have implemented @fluentui/react created few day back. I just copied node_modules\@fluentui folder from there and replaced in new solution, now my new solution is also working.